# How to get content of url by python (must be login in site)

Tags: python, curl, urllib2, urllib, urllib3

I want to get content of webpage by python but it has login .
so I must first login in to site then get my content.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Last time I tried this, I used http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/